# how to ignore one bundle from deployement to karaf in maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, apache-karaf, maven-deploy-plugin

I have 5 bundles in my Maven project. But i want only 4 of them to be deployed on karaf and moduleE to be compiled and generate its jar file only at another place.

Module E do not have any Activator class it just has one properties file (xml).

My POM file contains:

```
<modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
    <module>moduleC</module>
    <module>moduleD</module>
    <module>moduleE</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <karaf.deploy.build.folder>${env.KARAF_BASE}/deploy</karaf.deploy.build.folder>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

More information would be needed to answer comprehensively but, based on what you've posted, somewhere else in your pom or parent pom will be some plugin *configuration* which uses `karaf.deploy.build.folder`.

You would need to override that in Module E.

Something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>whatever.plugin.has.karaf.deploy.build.folder.mentioned.in.it</groupId>
    <artifactId>some.artifact</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```